# C# WPF Data from GridView on not selected Tab in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have TabControl with GridView on the each tab. GridViews have controltemplate like this:

```
 <Style  TargetType="GridView">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                   <GridView ItemSource={Binding Phases}/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I need to get data from all of them. I find GridView in template in each tab like this:

```
{
   FirstTabGridView.ApplyTemplate();    
   GridView dataGridView = (GridView)FirstTabGridView.Template.FindName("TemplatedGridView", FirstTabGridView);
}
```

All work when i'm get data from selected tab, but if tab never selected TemplatedGridView.Items is empty.
How i can solve this?

Comment: Could you expain us why would you need to access GridView in a Tab that hasn't been loaded/selected yet?

Comment: Please learn MVVM before ever writing a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: Because GridViews binded to collection, and i need to get data from this collection with filetering that present in GridViews. Also i'm use MVVM pattern.